# Custom Serialization using ReadObject and WriteObject

Tags: java, serialization, java-custom-serialization

I am trying to write a instance of pojo class by using WriteObject method. when i write code like this :

```
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException{ 
    oos.defaultWriteObject();    
    oos.writeObject(this);
}
```

It works fine but when I try and create a new local object and pass it to writeObject method it fails with

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

can some one please explain why it keeps calling writeObject method again and again recursively?

```
class Employee implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException{
        ois.defaultReadObject();
        Employee emp = (Employee)ois.readObject();
        emp.toString();
    }
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException{
        oos.defaultWriteObject();
        Employee emp = new Employee("sumit",10);
        oos.writeObject(emp);
    }
    public Employee(){

    }
    public Employee(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you share the entire class code please..

Comment: Link for the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rq6nW0XICDnRFXRp9Hanc14lonK21eiU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am unable to access it due to netwrok constraints..is it possible for you to add it here..

Comment: <blink>class Employee implements Serializable{
 private String name;
 private int age;
 private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException{
  ois.defaultReadObject();
  Employee emp = (Employee)ois.readObject();
  emp.toString();
 }
 private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException{
  oos.defaultWriteObject();
  Employee emp = new Employee("sumit",10);
  oos.writeObject(emp);
 }
 public Employee(){
  
 }
 public Employee(String name, int age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
 } 
}</blink>

Comment: Can you please add it with proper formatting..as code is quite difficult to figure out in this way

Comment: I could not format the comment so added in the post itself.

Comment: You should always add things in the post. The comments are for comments, not code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the fact that you are overriding `writeObject` method in your `Employee` class. So, when you create the `Employee` object and try to write it using `writeObject` method, it is called recursively leading to `StackOverflow` error.

But, when you do not write `Employee` object the code executes properly.

**---Edit as per the clarification asked in comment**

In your `Employee` class, you are overriding the `writeObject` method , so , whenever, you try to invoke `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject` with `Employee` as parameter, your overridden method will be invoked.
Now in your overridden `writeObject` in `Employee` class, you are again calling  `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject`( `oos.writeObject(emp);`) with Employee as parameter, thus, `writeObject` method of `Employee` class gets recursively called (**with new Employee object everytime**)and you get **stackoverflow** error.

Now in case when you try to call recursively `this` keyword, it is because of the fact that you try to invoke `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject` with the same instance of `Employee` class. As per the `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject` documentation at below mentioned link :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

*Multiple references to a single object are encoded using a reference sharing mechanism so that graphs of objects can be restored to the same shape as when the original was written.*

Infact, if you try the below code in your main method :

```
Employee emp = new Employee("sumit",10);
oos.writeObject(emp);
oos.writeObject(emp);
```

i.e if you invoke `writeObject` multiple times on same object, it is invoked only once.

Comment: how is serialization related to creation of object ? whatever i am passing should get saved right be it a new object or existing object ?

Comment: Actually I wanted to understand why it doesn't call recursively when I pass this object to writeObject method: oos.defaultWriteObject();
 oos.writeObject(this);

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is 'Employee' class is serializable. And you have overridden `writeObject` method in it.

Now in this `overridden` method, you are again creating an instance of `Employee` object and calling `writeObject` method of `oos`.

Serialization logic checks if the object being added is serializable. If it is, then serialize it or else throw `NotSerializable` exception.

Here, the object being added is `Serializable`. Hence it goes to serialize it and found that this `Object` has `writeObject` method overridden. So it calls that method.

Now again it goes to your overridden method logic and does the same method call again

```
oos.defaultWriteObject(); 
Employee emp = new Employee("sumit",10); 
oos.writeObject(emp);
```

and the loops continue, leading to `StackOverflow` error as it recursively calls it over and over again without breaking

Comment: Actually I wanted to understand why it doesn't call recursively when I pass this object to writeObject method:
oos.defaultWriteObject();
oos.writeObject(this);

Comment: how is serialization related to creation of object ? whatever i am passing should get saved right be it a new object or existing object ?

Comment: Because when you to `this`, you are basically passing the same object that you had passed, when calling the `writeObject` method in the first place, most probably in the `public static void main()`. But with the other code, you are again creating new object/reference of the same class leading to recursion

Comment: If you move your `writeObject` code to your mail class, the error should dis-appear. Because now `Employee` class haven't overriden `writeObject` and so it will be called only once